# EF: Editing a pivoted table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am making a scheduling application in Entity Framework/C#.

Hours are assigned to employees on a per-job, and per-week basis. So EmployeeA might be assigned to Job500 for 40 hours the week-ending May 19, 30 hours wk/e May 26, and so on. EmployeeA might also be assigned to Job501 for 10 hours wk/e May 26.

The way I have created the main table for scheduling is as follows:

```
jobID      | userID     | hours     | week-ending
500          EmployeeA    40          may-19-2017
500          EmployeeA    30          may-26-2017
501          EmployeeA    10          may-26-2017
500          EmployeeB    40          may-19-2017
```

The EF model:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public decimal hours { get; set; }
    public DateTime week_ending { get; set; }

    public virtual Job job { get; set; }
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
```

The idea is that eventually, the data is displayed in a **editable** HTML table like so:

```
JOB 500

userID           | May 19        | May 26      | June 2       | ........
EmployeeA          40              30
EmployeeB          30
```

So first the data would be selected  `WHERE jobID = the_job_being_viewed`.

Microsoft provides code examples on how to pivot EF data: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSEFPivotOperation-cbdd79db, but I have no idea as to how users can input new hour values in the pivoted table. I wanted to use the jQuery DataTable Editor plugin (**https://editor.datatables.net/**), but it looks like it can't edit pivoted tables.

My question can be summed up as follows: how might I manipulate the Schedule model to create an **editable** table as shown in the third code block above? I am open to commercially available solutions.

Comment: Curious - why don't you do the pivot in your query?

Comment: I did, but I don't know how I would edit it? I was under the impression that pivoted data can't be modified and saved back to the original table.

Comment: You can edit the data and then unpivot in order to update the original table.